# Simple Analogies for the Oberth Effect

Tags: optics, visible-light, metamaterials

I am just trying to create a simple analogy so that the Oberth effect makes sense.

Here is my best attempt:

The energy imparted by a photon to a mirror during reflection is very small. If put a material with some refractive index in front of the mirror, could I transfer a different energy from the photon into the mirror via the photon's reflection, as compared to the case where the mirror is in vacuum? This feels analogous to doing a burn in a gravity well and having it turn out more efficient.

Does this make sense, and is there a better analogy?

Comment: And is this a different case when the refractive index material is 'carried along' by the mirror, rather than existing in the space it is moving?

Comment: My gut says nothing changes if the material is carried along with the mirror but if the material is in free space (e.g. some liquid) then the 'oberth effect' applies. An analogy is reflecting an electron after accelerating it through a potential difference.

Comment: what does “different more energy” mean?  What is the relation to burning fuel in a well?  or metamaterials for that matter?  This is reflection on a regular material and it’s not like the photon has fuel to burn.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero edited. The photon can get redshifted. The refractive index material can carry momentum and energy. I have thought about it and it it seems just the oberth effect, except the photon cannot burn energy as you say (but it can do perfectly elastic collisons).

Imagine a material where the refractive index grows towards a point as 1/r. There are hyperbolic orbits and analogies to the oberth effect. It is like gravity-- but I am not sure how far the analogy can go.

Comment: Any sail can affect the momentum it captures from the wind by modulating the angle between wind and sail. Laser or solar sails are no different in this regard. Any light reflected will return to vacuum making the same angle with the sail normal, and the imparted momentum will be always in the opposite direction of this normal. Change the sail orientation and you change the normal

Comment: OK, I think the analogy is a bit complicated because energy/momentum for light are strange (normally energy is proportional to v^2). But you can do the analogy for a classical electron: fire a classical electron into a +ve potential well, it will undergo some hyperbolic trajectory, any momentum-changing interactions will effectively have been magnified (as compared to happening in free space) once the electron leaves the potential well. And actually you don't even need to go this far: the oberth effect applies to a pendulum! (in next comment)

Comment: Imagine a pendulum swinging. At any point you can apply some fixed momentum in the direction of the arc. How do you make it reach highest? Apply the momentum at the bottom of the swing, or at the top? You apply it at the bottom, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The light analogy isn't simple but here is a simple analogy to the Oberth effect:

Imagine a pendulum swinging. At any point you can apply some fixed momentum in the direction of the arc. How do you make it reach highest? Apply the momentum at the bottom of the swing, when the pendulum is fastest, or at the top, where it is slowest?

You apply it at the bottom, right?

If this is not obvious then your intuitive understanding of energy and momentum needs work (energy is proportional to v^2 and many things counterintuitive for most people follow on from this).